# Go でエラーが出た時StackTraceが見えなくなる

Tags: go

GoでGoroutine をたくさん使うプログラミングをしている時エラーが起こった時にGoroutineをすべてStackTraceに表示しようとするので1番肝心な最初のエラー箇所が見えなくなってしまいます。これを防ぐにはどうすればいいのでしょうか。

たくさんとは億単位のGoroutineです。

Comment: ファイルにリダイレクトしたらどうでしょうか

Comment: 一番上だけを表示する方法は無いのでしょうか。
できれば数十億行のファイルを作りたくはないです。

Comment: エラーがでるのが分かっているのであればすぐにCTRL+Cすればいいかと思います。

Comment: やってみましたが物理的にできませんでした。間に合いません。

Comment: リダイレクトしているのに間に合わないとは？

Comment: ./program > log.txtとしてやってみましたが、保存できませんでした。

Comment: 標準エラー出力をリダイレクトする場合は`./program 2> log.txt` とします。

Comment: なぜかできません。端末に表示されているのでリダイレクションがうまくできていないかファイルディスクリプタが違うようです。

Comment: `2>` の代わりに `>&` を試してみて下さい。

Comment: 一応、`GOTRACEBACK=0 go run ...` などとすればスタックトレースは表示されなくなります。ですが、表示されるのはエラーメッセージのみでエラーの発生箇所などは表示されません。